# Upgrade MacOS on a "MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 pouces, fin 2013)"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade MacOS's version, I am currently using : High Sierra 10.13.6

I have been avoiding it to prevent compatibility problems but I've seen to many times restrictions saying I can't use some software because my version is ancient...

But now that I am trying be up to date, and I actually can't do it. When I open the App Store, I have no available updates.

Is my machine too old, and won't work with the news OS ?

Edit1 : How do I upgrade ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the model number?

Comment: The most recent version you can run is Big Sur.

Comment: @red_menace, what can I add beside : MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inches, end 2013) ?

Comment: The actual model number always helps.  If nothing is showing up in Software Update, you can try the links in the previously answered question.

Comment: @red_menace I don't know what that number is and where to find it.

Comment: In the **About this Mac** dialog, the Hardware Overview of the System Report lists the model identifier.  As mentioned in an earlier comment, Big Sur is as far as you can go - Apple’s article on how to download is in the previously answered question.